# UnsupportedOperationException in Webflux Integration Test

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux

I am writing an integration test for the following Endpoint in my `Webflux` Service

```
@GetMapping
public Mono<ResponseEntity<List<UserWebModel>>> getUsers() {
    Flux<User> users = loadUserService.getusers(getUserIdFromToken());

    return users.collectList()
        .map(userList -> ResponseEntity.ok(userMapper.map(userList)))
        .switchIfEmpty(Mono.just(ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND).build()));
}
```

This Endpoint works fine when I start and test the service locally, but in my integration test I am getting an `UnsupportedOperationException`

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@AutoConfigureWebTestClient
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
public class UserIntegrationTest  {

  @Autowired
  private WebTestClient webTestClient;

  @Autowired
  private UserRepository userRepository;

  @BeforeAll
  void setup() {
    userRepository.saveAll(createMockUsers()).subscribe();
  }

  @AfterAll()
  void cleanup() {
    userRepository.deleteAll().subscribe();
  }

  @Test
  void test_getUsers() {
    initWiremockStubs();   

    this.webTestClient
        .mutateWith(mockJwt().jwt(jwt -> jwt.claim("userid", "12345")))
        .get()
        .uri("/users")
        .exchange()
        .expectStatus().isOk();
  }
```

Exception

`[ERROR] [] o.s.w.s.a.HttpWebHandlerAdapter - [4024b710] Error [java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException] for HTTP GET "/users", but ServerHttpResponse already committed (200 OK)
Error occurred after response was completed: OK(200 OK)[Vary:"Origin", "Access-Control-Request-Method", "Access-Control-Request-Headers", Content-Type:"application/json", Content-Length:"2", Cache-Control:"no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate", Pragma:"no-cache", Expires:"0", X-Content-Type-Options:"nosniff", X-Frame-Options:"DENY", X-XSS-Protection:"0", Referrer-Policy:"no-referrer"]
org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientRequestException: Error occurred after response was completed: OK(200 OK)[Vary:"Origin", "Access-Control-Request-Method", "Access-Control-Request-Headers", Content-Type:"application/json", Content-Length:"2", Cache-Control:"no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate", Pragma:"no-cache", Expires:"0", X-Content-Type-Options:"nosniff", X-Frame-Options:"DENY", X-XSS-Protection:"0", Referrer-Policy:"no-referrer"]
at app//org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.ExchangeFunctions$DefaultExchangeFunction.lambda$wrapException$9(ExchangeFunctions.java:136)
... 258 more
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
at org.springframework.http.ReadOnlyHttpHeaders.set(ReadOnlyHttpHeaders.java:108)`

While debugging I've found out, that an `EncoderHttpMessageWriter` is trying to write the `ContentLength` to `ReadOnlyHttpHeaders`, which leads to the `UnsupportedOperationException`.

```
if (inputStream instanceof Mono) {
    return body
        .singleOrEmpty()
        .switchIfEmpty(Mono.defer(() -> {
            message.getHeaders().setContentLength(0);
            return message.setComplete().then(Mono.empty());
        }))
        .flatMap(buffer -> {
            Hints.touchDataBuffer(buffer, hints, logger);
            message.getHeaders().setContentLength(buffer.readableByteCount()); // <--
            return message.writeWith(Mono.just(buffer)
                .doOnDiscard(DataBuffer.class, DataBufferUtils::release));
        })
        .doOnDiscard(DataBuffer.class, DataBufferUtils::release);
}
```

When I remove the response body in my endpoint the test works. What would be the issue here?